# How do I ignore the content in a txt file while plotting on Matlab?

Tags: matlab, data, plot

lovely friends!
The file in my impedance measurement data is in.txt format, with a title and numerous comments written on it. When I try to plot the data in Matlab, I get an error, which I assume is due to the text files.

Error using cat
Dimensions of arrays being concatenated are not consistent.

Error in cell2mat (line 75)
m{n} = cat(2,c{n,:});

So can anyone suggest to me how to get Matlab to disregard the sentences in the first few rows? in order to make the plot easier?

Best Regards

Comment: It is 801 by 5 array. here is the code
x= fopen('12AA.TXT','rt');
C = textscan(x,'%f%f%f%f%f');
fclose(x);
y = cell2mat(C);
semilogx(y(:,1:1),y(:,2:2))

Comment: what type is array C and what is the output of size(C)?

Comment: It is a numerical array but when I check on workspace it import as a character matrix

Comment: You need to change the way you import it then

Comment: Can you post a sample txt with dummy data that ha the exact same format as the original? One crude method, if you want to do this only once, is to use % symbol to "comment" out the lines which are not relevant to you. Many matlab data import methods ignore lines beginning with % symbol as though it were comments.

Comment: Another way, if you have an open file handle, is to call fgetl or similar function N times to skip the unwanted lines and *then* call textscan.